# CodeIgniter search results are unexpected; where() with or_like() broken?

Tags: mysql, database, codeigniter, search

- Today's date is April 25, 2013.  Yes, the time on the server is correct and a `var_dump` of `mdate('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime(now()))` is returning `2013-04-25`.
- The MySQL table column for `date` is the `date` type/format.
- CodeIgniter 2.1.3
- My search criteria string is `"test"`.

```
$criteria = array(
    'field1' => 'test',
    'field2' => 'test',
    'field3' => 'test'
);
```

---

The four items in my database that contain the word "test" are dated as follows:

```
date
2013-04-02
2013-04-05
2013-05-07
2013-05-21
```

---

In my model, when I want my search results (search = "test") to return everything no matter what the date, this is what it looks like...

```
$this->db->start_cache();       
$this->db->or_like($criteria);

$this->db->order_by('date', 'desc');

$this->db->stop_cache();        
$query['results'] = $this->db->get('table', $limit, $offset)->result_array();       
$this->db->flush_cache();       
return $query;
```

output as expected:

```
2013-05-21
2013-05-07
2013-04-05
2013-04-02
```

The above is working perfectly and all four items are returned.

---

However, when this is used and only a `where()` is added to refine the results to today and greater...

```
$this->db->start_cache();   
$this->db->or_like($criteria); // <-- remove this line and it works

$this->db->where('date >=', mdate('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime(now()))); // <-- only new line

$this->db->order_by('date', 'asc');

$this->db->stop_cache();    
$query['results'] = $this->db->get('table', $limit, $offset)->result_array();   
$this->db->flush_cache();   
return $query;
```

**unexpected** output:

```
2013-04-02 // <-- why this one??? today is 4/25
2013-05-07
2013-05-21
```

It's supposed to only show the results for today and in the future.  **So why is the item dated April 2, 2013 in there when today is April 25, 2013?**  (It's like it's partially working because it's still ignoring the item with `2013-04-05`.)

- why is this happening?
- how to fix this?

**EDIT**:

I've tried reversing the order:

```
$this->db->where('date >=', mdate('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime(now())));
$this->db->or_like($criteria);
```

and chaining:

```
$this->db->or_like($criteria)->where('date >=', mdate('%Y-%m-%d', strtotime(now())));
```

and this:

```
$this->db->or_like($criteria);
$this->db->where('DATE(date) >= DATE(NOW())');
```

Results are the same.

Comment: try using $this->db->last_query(); to see exactly what query code igniter is running for starters.  My guess would be the OR like is creating a general OR scenario and attaching the 04/02 date

Comment: Shouldn't or_like() use 2 parameters? `$this->db->or_like('column_name', $criteria);`

Comment: @Samutz, yes, my mistake in writing the question.  Edited.  `$criteria` is an array that contains several field names.

Comment: @JohnB, sorry for my mistake writing the question.  The `or_like()` is looking at three columns.  See my edited question.  Thanks.

Comment: You're probably not going to be able to build the query with Active Record if you want combined `OR` and `AND` conditions ... I'm assuming you want `WHERE (condition OR condition OR condition) AND date_condition` and what you're getting is `WHERE condition OR condition OR condition AND date_condition` which is completely different

Comment: @dleiftah, I'm slowly coming to the same conclusion.  What is the fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off, why don't you use the MySQL functions for date/time:

```
$this->db->where('DATE(date) >= DATE(NOW())');
```

(you might not need DATE(date), but only date)

However, like stated in comments, there's a chance your query isn't generated as you'd like, in terms of `and` and `or`. To test what the output query looks like, use `echo $this->db->last_query();`. You can always write the where part of the Active Records query using a custom string, like in my example above, which should fix the and/or issues.

All that should help you fix the problem.

EDIT

After a chat session, this is the final solution:

```
$where = "DATE(date) >= DATE(NOW()) 
          AND 
          (event LIKE '%$your_string%' 
          OR location LIKE '%$your_string%' 
          OR description LIKE '%$your_string%')";
$this->db->where($where);
```

Comment: I like `$this->db->where('DATE(date) >= DATE(NOW())');`, but it does not solve the root problem.  Also `echo $this->db->last_query()` is not doing anything.

Comment: Yeah, MySQL functions are better to use in... MySQL :) And faster...
You need to place the echo part after the `get` part of the AR... not sure if your caching disrupts it... if so, try to turn it off while testing.

Comment: Yes, the `echo` was last.  If I turn off the caching, then the results are even more  unpredictable.

Comment: I'm not experienced with this.  Can you please provide some guidance?  I'm trying to write out the query and it seems to be ignoring the `LIKE` portion and returning everything.

Comment: Wow, can you write here your full Active Records part (the final version), as well as what does the `echo` output?

Comment: "Wow", what?  The full Active Records part is in the OP.  The echo outputs nothing.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28923/discussion-between-shomz-and-sparky)

Comment: Just to confirm some things mention briefly in comments.  The issue was caused by using `or_like()` in conjunction with `where()`.

Answer (score 1):

I found the answer at ellislab forum https://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/185983/
Instead of using

```
$this->db->like('location', $your_string);
```

use:

```
$this->db->where('location LIKE', '%'.$your_string.'%');
```

and **or_where** instead of **or_like**.

Comment: Because you can use Codeigniter functions instead of normal query suggested in the accepted answer.

Comment: Accepted answer ***is*** using CI function `$this->db->where()` and your answer is using the same.

Comment: In my opinion, the accepted answer is classic query combined with CI function. I use only CI functions in my answer. My I am wrong, anyway...